# thead is appearing at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, pug, riot.js

I am working with pug(jade) and wanted to add rows based on the value of some variable. But the following code doesn't seem to work, it is giving tbody data after the thead.

```
row
  tbody
    tr
      td Data
    tr
      td Metrics
  script.
    console.log("Initializing row")

stats
  .container-fluid
    table
      thead
        tr
          th Column #1
      row(each='{ [1,2,3] }')
```

For some reason custom tag is rendered before thead. Anyidea what am I missing here...?

Comment: Are you trying to use `row` as a [mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html)?

Comment: Hey Sean Thanks for the comment, but it is solved now using tbody and looping for it.